# Exception while getting values from Mocked object using Mockito

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am writing junit using mockito for a Spring @component class.
When it try to access the static field from final constant file throwing Null pointer exception.

CruserDomainTest

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CruserTest {
    @InjectMocks
    CruserDomain eDomain = new CruserDomain();

    @Test
    public void testGetCruseById() throws Exception,
          {
        String cCode = "AA";
        int employeeId = 21305;
        when(
                cruseRepository.getTestId(
                        anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(
                buildAndReturnList());
        when(
                payDomain.getRefPay(anyString(),
                        anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
                .thenReturn(buildPay());
        CruseMember expectedResponse = eDomain.getMemberById(
                airlineCode, employeeId);


    }
```

CruserDomain

```
    //getting null pointer exception in the below line execution
//while getting the current month

 public CruseMember getMemberById(String cCode, int employeeId)
        throws Exception {

  //Some code //

        if (contractMonth.getType().equals(
                    CruseConstant.CURRENT_MONTH)) {
                currentMonthStartDate = cMonth.getStartDate();
            } else if (contractMonth.getType().equals(
                    CruseConstant.OTHER_MONTH)) {
                nextMonthStartDate = cMonth.getStartDate();
            }
```

CruseConstant:

```
public final class  CruseConstant { 

    public static final String CURRENT_MONTH = "C";
    public static final String OTHER_MONTH = "O";
    }
```

I tried with ReflectionTestutils but throwing exception while junit starts.

Help me on how to lookup final class static variables in the injectMocked class.

Comment: `@InjectMocks` has been known to fail silently when it fails to inject a dependency.  Have you tried implementing a `@Before` method in your test and Mocking the dependencies yourself?

Comment: I used @Before Reflection Test utils to set those values but getting error.Is there any other way apart from reflection testutil to set values for those constants

Comment: Statics should not be mocked with Mockito, and you don't need to use Reflection to set the constants, just let the method use the real constants.

Comment: Im doing tat way only but getting null pointer exception

Comment: In the comment before my previous, you told me you weren't using the real constants, but Reflection Test utils to set the values for those constants.  In any case part of your problem may be the fact that `@InjectMocks` has been known to fail silently in certain edge cases, which I have reason to believe your code falls into.  Consider creating the mocks you need (notably, `cruzeRepository` and `payDomain` using [these directions](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/), which may solve your problem.

Comment: Since this is the service method without inject mock  annotation it throwing all the other stubs throwing null pointer exception

Comment: So what does your `@Before` method look like when you remove the `@InjectMocks` annotation?  Did you mock those other stubs in it?

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie Correction : it has been **designed** to fail silently, and for good reason !

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to not mock domain objects, instead I would craft builders that can generate those objects.

---

Also in the code snippet `@InjectMocks` has no mock to inject, so injects nothing, mock fields should be declared in the test class. However I stress the point of not mocking the domain !

We've written this page on how to write good tests, I think TDD practitioners should read it, wether they use mockito or not. Lot of people contributed to refine this wiki page.

=> https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to understand your code because you have replaced the interesting parts with comments, but I would guess that you get a NPE because

```
contractMonth
```

is null. That is because you did not mock and/or forgot to define the behaviour of the class that you get the contractMonth from (CruserRepository?)